# Was Kulbhushan Jadhav an Indian spy working for RAW?

Tags: india, pakistan

On 3 March 2016, Pakistani security forces [arrested an Indian person from Pakistan's restive Baluchistan province](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kulbhushan_Jadhav). They also recovered an ID and a passport from him. The ID said he was a "serving Indian naval officer" named "Kulbhushan Jadhav". The passport said he was a "businessman" named "Hussain Mubarak Patel". Pakistani side maintained that he was working for the Indian intelligence agency RAW and was sent to Baluchistan to assist Baluch separatists militants.

India is saying that the captured person was actually a retired naval officer, currently a businessman based in Chabahar of Iran, and either Pakistani security forces or their hands kidnapped him.

Was Kulbhushan Jadhav an Indian spy working for RAW?

Comment: It feels disingenuous for you to ask us whether Jadhav was a spy, and then [post a question on Politics.SE](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/54711/20220) asserting that he was without waiting for an answer.

Comment: With the time running out on the bounty, and a high risk that my answer will be receiving (half of) it, presumably against your desire, perhaps you could share what you consider a "reputable source" is. To me, the whole weakness of the question is that there is no way to answer the question except by referring to the Pakistani court. Anyone else is just expressing an opinion, not an official ruling.

Answer (score 3):

Skeptics.SE is not a court of law. We can't decide on the guilt or innocence of a person - we can only report what courts have found.

The Pakistani Army court martialed Kulbhushan Jadhav, accepted a confession and sentenced him to death. [[Press Release](https://twitter.com/OfficialDGISPR/status/851365691898724352)]

The [Indian Government denied](https://zeenews.india.com/news/india/alleged-indian-spy-arrested-in-pakistan-is-ex-naval-officer-no-connection-to-govt-mea-tells-islamabad_1869157.html) that he was a spy.

> “The said individual has no link with the Government since his premature retirement from Indian Navy."

The [International Court of Justice ruled](https://www.icj-cij.org/en/case/168) that Pakistan had breached the Vienna convention by failing to give Jadhav consular access before the trial, and required that Pakistan review the conviction and sentence in light of this.